Is there a relationship between もっと and もっとも?
Dictionaries list もっと and もっとも as two separate words (and with different pitch patterns):

もっと (も＼っと): Adverb that means "(some) more; even more; longer; further"

もっとも (もっと＼も): Adverb that means "most; extremely"


But is (2) just もっと + the も particle? (literally meaning something like "even (も) longer (もっと)")? Or is the resemblance just coincidental?

Supposedly both もっとも{HLLL} and もっとも{HHHL} are possible for 最も.
